# How to insert a reactive value into rhandsontable?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, rhandsontable

I'm trying to insert a reactive value, from a separate user input, into a table rendered using **rhandsontable**. An example code is posted at the bottom of this post. Immediately below is an image that best explains what I'm trying to do. Any recommendations for how to do this?

[image]

Code:

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

mydata <- data.frame('Series 1' = c(1,12,0,1), check.names = FALSE)
rownames(mydata) <- c('Term A','Term B','Term C','Term D') 

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(), 
  br(),
  uiOutput("choices"),
  rHandsontableOutput('hottable')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  uiTable <- reactiveVal(mydata)
  
  observeEvent(input$hottable, {uiTable(hot_to_r(input$hottable))})
  
  output$hottable <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(uiTable(),rowHeaderWidth = 100, useTypes = TRUE)%>%
      hot_context_menu(allowRowEdit = FALSE, allowColEdit = FALSE) %>%
      hot_cols(
        colWidths = 80,
        renderer = "function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
           Handsontable.renderers.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
           if(instance.params && 1 === row) {td.style.background = '#eff0f1'} // shade row 2 only
         }"
      ) %>%
    hot_row(c(2), readOnly = TRUE)  # makes row 2 non-editable
  })
  
  output$choices <- 
    renderUI(
      selectInput(
        "choices", 
        label = "User selects value to reflect in row 2 of table below:",
        choices = c(1,2,3)
      )
    )

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: @CuriousJorge-user9788072 is this your second account? - those graphics seem familiar :-)

Comment: Hahaha yes! I had a feeling you would notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add another `observeEvent` to modify the reactiveVal `uiTable`:

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

mydata <- data.frame('Series 1' = c(1,1,0,1), check.names = FALSE)
rownames(mydata) <- c('Term A','Term B','Term C','Term D') 

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(), 
  br(),
  uiOutput("choices"),
  rHandsontableOutput('hottable')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  uiTable <- reactiveVal(mydata)
  
  observeEvent(input$hottable, {uiTable(hot_to_r(input$hottable))})
  
  output$hottable <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(uiTable(),rowHeaderWidth = 100, useTypes = TRUE)%>%
      hot_context_menu(allowRowEdit = FALSE, allowColEdit = FALSE) %>%
      hot_cols(
        colWidths = 80,
        renderer = "function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
           Handsontable.renderers.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
           if(instance.params && 1 === row) {td.style.background = '#eff0f1'} // shade row 2 only
         }"
      ) %>%
      hot_row(c(2), readOnly = TRUE)  # makes row 2 non-editable
  })
  
  output$choices <- 
    renderUI({
      selectInput(
        "choices", 
        label = "User selects value to reflect in row 2 of table below:",
        choices = c(1,2,3)
      )
    })
  
  observeEvent(input$choices, {
    tmpTable <- uiTable()
    tmpTable$`Series 1`[2L] <- as.numeric(input$choices)
    uiTable(tmpTable)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

PS: are you aware of the fact, that you can embed dropdowns directly in rhandsontable? Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57634100/is-there-a-way-to-have-different-dropdown-options-for-different-rows-in-an-rhand/57755862#57755862).